# Changing the threshold to activate mouseover event in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I currently have a mouseover function working properly in a leaflet map.  I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to change the threshold of when the popup occurs on the mousover.  As is, the mouse cursor has to be directly over the point (this is point-data) in order to activate the pop-up.  Ideally, this threshold would be bigger, so that a mouseover within a reasonable vicinity of the feature, maybe a few pixels, would activate the popup.  Here is my existing code:

```
    layer.on({
        mouseover: function(){
        this.openPopup();
    },
    mouseout: function(){
        this.closePopup();
    },
    click: function(){
        $("#panel").html(popupContent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Leaflet.GeometryUtil](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil) plugin:

> A collection of utilities for Leaflet geometries (linear referencing, etc.)

```js
map.on("mousemove", function(event) {
  var result = L.GeometryUtil.closestLayerSnap(
    map,
    all, // array of layers that can be "snapped" to.
    event.latlng, // mouse position.
    30); // distance in pixels under which snapping occurs.

  if (result) {
    result.layer.fire("mouseover");
  } // Note: since the mouse may never go "over" the marker,
    // it may never go "out", hence never trigger "mouseout" event.
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/50/